# How to have multi-flow for automated testing in postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

As mentioned in the title, How to have multi-flow for automated testing in postman?

For example, I have these end-points:

- Create a user
- Delete a user
- Create a post (needs a user)

I need automated tests like:

- **Flow 1:** Create a user > Delete a user
- **Flow 2:** Create a user > Create a post (needs a user)

I mean that I need to run multi test-flow.

Comment: just put `flow 1` to a folder, and `flow 2` to another one.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 It has its own folders and collections. It may be changed sometime. and it has about 250 end-points.

Comment: I understand but this is the way you do auto test with postman, duplicate request in many folders to make the pre-condition or a step in a flow.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 It will be hard if I used copy past because I will lose collection updates.

Comment: Yes, It'd be the bad practice, cannot apply "DRY" in postman, sad but true. I prefer using postman for manual test and api documentation, not for automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **one folder** for **one use case**,
Each use case might have multiple testcases, create subfolders accordingly

[image]

Do not worry about duplicate request created in the subfolders, each testcases(folder/subfolder) should be independent. so that we can execute folders independently

like,

[image]